# Generate sequence of realized Cash flows from an IRS under a given scenario using QuantLib

Tags: c++, quantlib

I am new to quantlib, but I have relatively good understanding of C++. To put my question in some sort of context, I can inform you that I am actually trying to implement the portfolio CVA calculation method proposed by Giovanni Cesari (see link below) for a simple portfolio consisting of one interest rate swap (as a starting point).

I working with the Cheyette (quasi-Gaussian) interest rate model. The model has been implemented as a "new" *stochastic process* class and the simulated paths stored/generated as a *multipath* class.

However, as Cesari's method is based on LS-Monte Carlo, I need to write a code that can generate the resulting cash flow sequence from an interest rate swap under each scenario. I do not know if there is some efficient way to do this in quantlib, but I have a feeling that there is. I guess one should be able let the scenarios generated, populate Quantlib *quotes* which are linked to an instance of the quantlib *term structures* class. Hopefully I can use this together with the *swap* class in order to obtain the realized cash flows (basically the floating leg, as the fixed leg is deterministic) from the swap.

Any idea of how this can be done will be highly appreciated!

Link to Cesari's presentation (see page 21 to 26): http://sfi.epfl.ch/files/content/sites/sfi/files/shared/Swissquote%20Conference%202010/Cesari_talk.pdf

Comment: If my interpretation to the question is correct, are you asking to get a path of IRS for each scenario in MC?

Comment: Well, it depends on what you mean by path. Lets say that we have generated a single scenario, so that we "know" the evolution of the yield curve from t=0 to t=T. What I am asking for is some input on how I efficiently can get a vector containing the realized cashfows of the IRS under this scenario.